# How can I read a GET element from url via javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, get

My URL looks like this one:
`http://www.something.hu/#/ask?kerdesPost=fdasdas%20ad%20asd%20ad%20asdas`

I would like to get only `fdasdas%20ad%20asd%20ad%20asdas` or only `kerdesPost=fdasdas%20ad%20asd%20ad%20asdas`.

How can I do it via JavaScript? What is the shortest way?

Comment: I tried that like this:
`function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var alma = getParameterByName('kerdesPost');
alert(alma);
`, But gives me empty alert window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
if((window.location.href).indexOf('?') != -1) {
    var queryString = (window.location.href).substr((window.location.href).indexOf('?') + 1); 

    // "queryString" will now contain kerdesPost=fdasdas%20ad%20asd%20ad%20asdas

    var value = (queryString.split('='))[1];

    // "value" will now contain fdasdas%20ad%20asd%20ad%20asdas

    value = decodeURIComponent(value);

    // "value" will now contain fdasdas ad asd ad asdas (unescaped value)
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBbud/)

This should get you what you need.

Comment: This is exactly working. It's very easy to implement and it gives me that I exactly need. Thank you very much.